# error: alternative gem can't be master: it is a slave of ruby

Tags: ruby, gem

I am struggling to get ruby up and running, and i get this message in many installations

> update-alternatives: error: alternative gem can't be master: it is a slave of ruby

The full message:

> update-alternatives: error: alternative gem can't be master: it is a slave of ruby
>   dpkg: error processing rubygems1.8 (--configure):
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libruby1.8-extras:
>   libruby1.8-extras depends on libgems-ruby1.8 | rubygems1.8; however:
>    Package libgems-ruby1.8 is not installed.
>    Package rubygems1.8 is not configured yet.
>   dpkg: error processing libruby1.8-extras (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Setting up libsqlite3-ruby1.8 (1.2.4-2.1) ...
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error 
> >from a previous failure.
>
> > Setting up libsqlite3-ruby (1.2.4-2.1) ...
> >     Setting up libxml-simple-ruby (1.0.12-1) ...
> >     Setting up rake (0.8.7-1) ...
> >     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rails:
> >     rails depends on libruby1.8-extras; however:
> >      Package libruby1.8-extras is not configured yet.
> >     dpkg: error processing rails (--configure):
> >     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
> >     No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error 
> > from a previous failure.
> >                                    
> >                                                                            >Setting up zip (3.0-2) ...
> >     Errors were encountered while processing:
> >     rubygems1.8
> >     libruby1.8-extras
> >     rails
> >     E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

ubuntu 10.4 
ruby1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use RVM(rvm.io)?